# Proxy Settings Chromium Embedded

Tags: delphi, tchromium

How to set manually proxy settings Ip:Port to Chromium Embedded. That will affect only the control not globaly like it is if you set it for IE.

Thanks

Comment: I'm wondering why this was downvoted and nominated to close ? It's not the best formed question, but it's understandable. OP just wants to use own proxy settings, not those from WinHTTP-based proxy resolver. And that's not as easy as seems to be!

Comment: Are you using [`DCEF3`](http://code.google.com/p/dcef3/) or the old [`Delphi Chromium Embedded`](http://code.google.com/p/delphichromiumembedded/) ?

Comment: @TLama I am using DCEF3 seems like that this is a bug in CEF3 :)

Comment: Seems so, [`author said`](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/delphichromiumembedded/rdxI5S6-2yo) that some issue with proxy should be fixed and I've tried the trick with the `CefGetProxyForUrl` he mentioned [`here`](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/delphichromiumembedded/BeLr4uYTOFs), but that procedure is never passed. I've tried it with the most recent trunk version.

Comment: @TLama I'll wait for a while until it actually is stable enough.

Comment: @TLama Have you figured it out for DCEF1 ?

Answer (score 1):

In CEF 3 you can use the `--proxy-server` command line switch. An example value would be `socks5://127.0.0.1:8888`. You can set it programmatically in `CefApp::OnBeforeCommandLineProcessing`. When setting it in this callback name shouldn't contain the `--` prefix.

Answer (score 1):

The greater control is obtainable using a previously existing class, **CefProxyHandler**. 
Newest implementations uses only command line flags (I found these inferior). You can find previous code on [older SVN branches of CEF](https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/source/browse/#svn%2Fbranches%2F1453%2Fcef1%2Finclude%253Fstate%253Dclosed).

I have implemented in this way (the following are C++ directions on Windows - I won't paste much code since it can be read from the URL above):

- implement exported **CefProxyHandler** class following the other CEF class example (such as CefApp); class have a single method, *GetProxyForUrl*

- in cef_types.h define the **cef_proxy_type_t** enumeration (direct, named, PAC) and the **cef_proxy_info_t** struct (contains type and string list)

- in cef_types_wrappers.h define **CefProxyInfoTraits** over **cef_proxy_info_t** (follow the other structures example), and class **CefProxyInfo : public CefStructBase**

- in libcef/browser/browser_main.cc in **PreMainMessageLoopRun** replace **ProxyServiceFactory::CreateProxyConfigService** with **CefProxyServiceFactory::CreateProxyConfigService**; Cef factory will create a **CefProxyService**, which finally creates a **CefProxyConfigService**
- inspired from *src/net/proxy/proxy_config_service_win.cc* implement class **CefProxyConfigServiceWin**; main thing is

```
static void GetCurrentProxyConfig(net::ProxyConfig* config) {
  CefRefPtr<CefApp> app = CefContentClient::Get()->application();
  if(app.get()) {
    CefRefPtr<CefProxyHandler> handler = app->GetProxyHandler();
    if(handler.get()) {
      // ... use handler->GetProxyForUrl etc.
    }
  }

  WINHTTP_CURRENT_USER_IE_PROXY_CONFIG ie_config = {0};
  if (!WinHttpGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser(&ie_config)) {
    LOG(ERROR) << "WinHttpGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser failed: " <<
      GetLastError();
    *config = net::ProxyConfig::CreateDirect();
    config->set_source(net::PROXY_CONFIG_SOURCE_SYSTEM_FAILED);
    return;
  }
  SetFromIEConfig(config, ie_config);
  FreeIEConfig(&ie_config);
}
```

- re-add net::ProxyConfigServiceWin::set_force_auto_detect which was present in [older releases](https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/source/browse/branches/1364/cef1/libcef/browser_request_context.cc?r=1153)

- in libcef/browser/url_request_context_getter.cc (inspire from older CEF branches) implement **ProxyConfigServiceNull : public net::ProxyConfigService** (all empty implementation), **class CefProxyResolver : public net::ProxyResolver** (here is where **GetProxyForUrl** is), and in **CefURLRequestContextGetter::GetURLRequestContext()** check for custom proxy handler, such as:

```
bool fCustomProxyHandler = false;
CefRefPtr<CefApp> app = CefContentClient::Get()->application();
if(app.get()) {
    CefRefPtr<CefProxyHandler> handler = app->GetProxyHandler();
    if(handler.get()) {
    #if defined(OS_WIN)
      // Force auto-detect so the client resolver will be called.
      net::ProxyConfigServiceWin::set_force_auto_detect(true);
    #endif
      // The client will provide proxy resolution.
      storage_->set_proxy_service(
          new net::ProxyService(
                                net::ProxyService::CreateSystemProxyConfigService(io_loop_->message_loop_proxy(), file_loop_), 
                                new CefProxyResolver(handler), 
                                NULL
                               )
      );
      fCustomProxyHandler = true;
    }
}
if(!fCustomProxyHandler) {
    //  custom proxy resolution not provided
    scoped_ptr<net::ProxyService> system_proxy_service;
    system_proxy_service.reset(
        ProxyServiceFactory::CreateProxyService(
            NULL,
            url_request_context_.get(),
            url_request_context_->network_delegate(),
            CefContentBrowserClient::Get()->proxy_config_service().release(),
            command_line));
    storage_->set_proxy_service(system_proxy_service.release());
}
```

The key thing is to provide storage_->set_proxy_service your own implementation. 
Last thing to do is to provide CefProxyHandler (previous versions could be added in CefApp or CefClient, similarly with life span handler, request handler etc). The example above is providing it from CefApp.
Newest branches (2357, maybe lower) separates more between browser process handler and app. It's up to you, all is needed is acces the proxy handler provider (usually CefApp) via available global context getters and from application either get proxy handler directly and call GetProxyHandler, or browser process handler (if you plan to add proxy getter there), CefClient etc. 
After that, you can easily have your GetProxyHandler query your app for proxy settings (post task, PostMessage with WaitForSingleObject if you're on Windows etc.) so proxy server/port/user/pass are retrieved via GetProxyForUrl.

Doing so, although not easy, will offer you complete control - you can even handle proxy *per url* if you want to, change dynamically inside the same browser/renderer/plugin without need for restarting (keep in mind things such as pending downloads or even plugin streaming may be impacted).

Comment: OnBeforeCommandLineProcessing have two problems: can set proxy only at process start, and when user/pass are involved, they are passed in clear text. An encoding form is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
uses ceflib;

procedure AppCefGetProxyForUrl(const url: ustring; var proxyType: TCefProxyType;
  var proxyList: ustring );
begin
  proxyType := CEF_PROXY_TYPE_NAMED;
  proxyList := 'ip:port';
end;

initialization
  CefGetProxyForUrl := @AppCefGetProxyForUrl;

end.
```

Comment: How to use this in a Class? Without Initialization